# How do I remove Xdebug's styles and additional info shown in my browser?

Tags: php, xdebug

So after installing Xdebug the way the output is shown changed. There's additional info about the callstack and some styling. 
Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Now if I want to get back to the default (no styling and no call stack info) how do I disable it?

Comment: If you just want to get shot of the styling, you can switch off HTML errors `ini_set('html_errors', 0);` - I'm not sure you _can_ suppress the stack trace completely whilst having xdebug enabled.

Comment: @CD001 it would be nice to post as answer

Comment: @Jimmmy ... I'm *fairly* sure it's a duplicate, I think I found out about switching off `html_errors` with XDebug from SO in the first place - just not able to find the duplicate right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `display_errors` to Off in your `php.ini` file. Or, add `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` to the start of your PHP file.

Please note that this will suppress errors in the browser.

Comment: I want to get the errors but I don't want the styling and call stack info. I want to get the defaults back.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable xdebug extension in WAMP via PHP Extentions menu or in your `php.ini` file by commenting the line with a `;`

`;zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"`